# Sharing computer internet connection with LG - P990 (Optimus 2x)

Tags: reverse-tether

Is any way to connect the LG-P990 (optimus2x) to internet by sharing a computer connection? I am frequently traveling abroad and the data fees in roaming are very high and I have available the internet on my laptop.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is called Reverse tethering, and it can be done with several apps, like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me). You can find a quick introduction to it [here](http://support.connectify.me/entries/20306902-getting-started-with-connectify).